# Receive intent in an non activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am doing a task now in which I have to take the No. of rows and the images as the input and then divide the images into the given no. of rows equally.

I feel that its almost done except for one block. I have to receive the images `intent` passed from the main Activity class in the class which extends the `BaseAdapter`.

**How to receive an intent from a non activity class??**

I browsed and searched a lot. All just intend and give solutions to pass the intent from the non activity class but not to receive the intent from the non activity class.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you want to pass data from activity to adapter class.

Comment: Yeah.. But my Adapter class is an inner class of the MainActivity which extends the Activity class.. How can I access them. I created objects and even tried referencing from the context and this. But it did not work out. Can you please help me??

Comment: you got answer for this Question...

Comment: No.. I have not got the answer. I am not able to access the outer class intent via the inner class. Please help me out..

Comment: Then why you selected below answer was correct.any way. i am not clear about your requirement can you please elaborate it. tell me about about your requirement what do you want to do.

Comment: See I have a main activity in which I take the input of number of rows and images. On button click i am passing an intent to another activity which loads the images into the gridView.. But the problem is the view has to be created in the class which extends the BaseAdapter class, which is my inner class of the class which extends the activity class. I have to recieve the number of images recieved in my getView delegate method. So I have to access the intent in the class extending the BaseAdapter class. I am not able to do it. Thats the problem. Please help me out. I am at a fix

Comment: When you are calling adapter pass those values or declare those values as global variables you can get those values in any places...

Comment: Its not working.. I tried the way you told.. Help me to fix the bug..

Comment: Can you post some code here what you tried i will tell where you did wrong...

Comment: I tried posting but it dint get posted. If you can give your ID, i will be greatful.. Coz am unable to post the code here... So

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code it will help you, declare those values as global variables you can get those values in any places...

```
public class Animate extends Activity {

GridView gridView;
int img;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    img = i.getIntExtra("ImageViews", 0);       

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setNumColumns(3);
    gridview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Animate anim = new Animate();
    private Context mContext;
    int fadeInDuration = 6000;
    int timeBetween = 5000;
    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {              
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            grid = vi.inflate(R.layout.animation, null);
        }

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);
        image.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                animation.reset();
                Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.00f);
                fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);
                fadeIn.setStartOffset(5000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {                 

            }
        });
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Pratibha.

It is not possible in Android, but you can do one thing: define the class which is extending the `BaseAdapter` as sub class inside the class which is extending `Activity` so that you can directly access those data inside the sub class without passing through an intent

Comment: My class which is extending the BaseAdapter class is the inner class of the main class extending activity. Now i just need to access the intent from ImageAdapter class which is recieved in the MainActivity class. Can you please help me?? please

Comment: Can you tell me where actually your ImageAdapter class is located..?

Comment: you can do one thing create a global object inside the Activity class and then assign the data you got through Intent in the outer class and you can use the same object inside the inner class make sure before using it check for its Null ness

Comment: I have nested the Main Activity class and the inner class of MainActivity is the Adapter class.. Thanks a lot for the reply.. I will try the way you have told :)